# IF statements and VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry if this is a really stupid question, it's been a while since I have done much work in Excel

Basically I want to look at the value in cell I26 and if it equals 25 then do a VLOOKUP on one table and if it equals 26 then do a VLOOKUP on another table. Eventually I will have additional tables for 27,28,29 and 30.

This is what I have so far but I just keep getting "#N/A". Where am I going wrong?

=IF(I24=25,VLOOKUP(I24,M15:N52,2,FALSE),IF(I24=26,VLOOKUP(I24,Q15:R52,2,FALSE)))

Thanks

Comment: It could be that no match is happening.  Have you checked your data for this?

Comment: No you're right I should have been doing the VLOOKUP on cell I27!

Comment: Blame the work Xmas party yesterday and a bad hangover!

Comment: Your logic looks fine to me from a quick glance.

Comment: Yeah we're having our party tomorrow morning, but no alcohol.

Comment: You are missing the 'Value if false" for the second IF statement. You should add one for instances where it cannot find a value in either vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a value if false for the second lookup. Also, I always put an `IFERROR()` around it also so that if it's looking for a value, it's say it's missing instead of giving an error `=IFERROR(IF(I26=25,VLOOKUP(I26,M15:N52,2,FALSE),IF(I26=26,VLOOKUP(I26,Q15:R52,2,FALSE),"It's not 25 or 26")),I26 & " isn't in the tables")`

Happy hangover!